# How to get Material 2 (Angular 4) autocomplete to searching an external API

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I'm trying to get Angular Material 2 autocomplete to work search an API instead of search inside an array as per example. This is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="33" class="mr-20 mt-20">
  <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
      <span>{{ state.name }}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
  .startWith(null)
  .debounceTime(400)
  .do(value => {
    this.ClientsService.search(value).then( res => {
      console.log(res, 'oi');
      this.states = res;
    })
  });
```

However, when I type, I get this error: `Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'e' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Note that `e` is what I type in the search field. The response I'm getting from the server is an array with objects in it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you get values in `filteredStates`

Comment: You have forgotten to parse the data that you  that you get from server  into JSON.
Do a JSON.parse() and it should work

Comment: @Timothy I'm parsing the data on the service end, so its not that. When I tried to parse the data again I got the same error.

Comment: @RahulSingh yes I do get an array with objects in it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is `states` that you want to show in your template, as per what you are storing your incoming data to, then that is what you want to show in template.

So do:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.name">
```

instead of

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
```

with TS:

```
this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
  .startWith(null)
  .debounceTime(400)
  .do(value => {
    this.ClientsService.search(value).then( res => {
      console.log(res, 'oi');
      this.states = res;
    })
  })
  .subscribe()
```

Plunker with random Chuck Norris jokes ;) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uu4cya?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: When I tried your code I got the following error: `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.` `Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<string[]>'.` What version of Angular are you using? I'm on 4.4.5 and Material 2, beta 12

Comment: Yeah, `filteredStates` needs to be a `Subscription` in this case instead of Observable, so it should be declared `filteredStates: Subscription;` I think that should do it :)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear! :) :)

Comment: A last question would be, how can I display the object name instead of id? On the html part, I've changed `[value]="state.name"` to `[value]="state.id"` which when using the form value is right as I get the ID, however, this is part of a stepper and it replaces the name for the id.

Comment: Uhmm... you can have the `value` as the `state.id`, but in the interpolation show whatever you want, in that case the `state.name` in your span, right? Or am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: On the interpolation is right (I'm using state.name) and while selecting, it shows the name, however after selecting it, it goes back to id

Comment: I don't really now understand the problem at hand here, maybe I'm stupid :D Could you create a demo which now shows the issue and I'd be happy to take a look. Since I don't at all understand what **after selecting it, it goes back to id** means :)

Comment: @AJT82 , After selection of option from autocomplete valuechanges is still running it. can we prevent that after selection

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have forgotten to parse the result that you are getting from server.

```
this.states = JSON.parse(res);
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: As mentioned in previous comment, the data is being parsed on the service end, so that's not it. I've even tried your suggestion but I still got the same error.